# Is it possible to Connect IBM Mainframe DB2 Using Karate framework?

Tags: db2, karate, mainframe

Is it possible to connect IBM Mainframe DB2 using karate framework ? Tried to connect SQL server and it works but facing issue with IBM Mainframe DB2 .. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see that this question has been shut down as duplicate. I'm not convinced it is (like, it's been dealt with as though it's in a Karate-only forum and nobody else could help, but in reality you tagged it db2 and mainframe too). However, if you raise the question again, you're going to need to provide a whole lot more information about what the Db2 issue is you're seeing. Errors, logs, code, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: anything you can do with Java can be used by Karate, so it is completely up to you. Maybe you have to find the right person who knows how to make a JDBC call to DB2 running on a mainframe, this has nothing to do with Karate.